# Burning a DVD for standalone player in linux

Tags: command-line, dvd

I would like to burn DVD+R for standalone player in Linux from command line

Please some one help me in this.

Comment: "from command line" is the hard part here, you could do it the easy way & use a gui program like k3b or brasero

Answer (score 0):

Try the below command to write into blank CD.

sudo wodim dev=/dev/scd0 blank=disc

Hope this helps.

Comment: Doesn't `wodim` need an iso file ready to be burnt? Would need to create the iso first with something like `genisoimage` right?

Answer (score 0):

Here's Ubuntu's help page about CD/DVD Burning

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CdDvd/Burning

Highlights include:

### Burning a CD or DVD using Command Line tools

This section details the use of the command line(terminal) to burn either a CD or DVD disk.

#### Creating an ISO image

A command called mkisofs can make an .ISO image to be burned or mounted.

```
genisoimage -r -J -o cd_image.iso /directory
```

The -r and -J ensures long file names work for Unix (using Rock Ridge) and Windows (using Joliet extensions) respectively.

#### Checking CD Images Before Burning

It's possible to check CD images before burning. The easiest way is to simply double-click on it from the file browser, which will view the image with the Archive Manager.

If you have sudo access, you can also mount the image, and explore its contents

```
sudo modprobe loop
sudo mount -t iso9660 -o ro,loop=/dev/loop0 cd_image.iso /media/cdrom
```

Remember to unmount an image after checking:

```
sudo umount /media/cdrom
```

### Burning a CD on the Command Line with wodim

cdrecord can burn an ISO(.iso) disk image or other data onto a CD. To burn a data CD (using image prepared earlier):

First see where the CDROM/DVDROM is located. Something like this

```
$ wodim --devices
wodim: Overview of accessible drives (1 found) :
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
 0  dev='/dev/scd0'     rwrw-- : 'LITE-ON' 'DVDRW SOHW-1633S'
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

After finding the info. from device scanning, take the appropriate target. This is important if there are more than one device on the system.

In my case /dev/cdrw and /dev/dvdrw both point to /dev/scd0

```
$ ls -l /dev/cdrw
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 2009-01-26 21:56 /dev/cdrw -> scd0

$ ls -l /dev/dvdrw
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 2009-01-26 21:56 /dev/dvdrw -> scd0
```

Hence one can use the following notation :-

```
wodim dev=/dev/cdrw -v -data cd_image.iso
```

To burn an audio cd from wav files:

```
wodim dev=/dev/cdrw -v -audio [wav files...]
```

Replace /dev/cdrw as needed if this is not your CD-Writer

-v (verbose) lets you track the recording progress

---

[End of Ubuntu Help]

Here's a little multi-session excerpt from `man wodim`, the man (manual) page for `wodim`

```
   -multi Allow multi session CDs to  be  made.  This  flag  needs  to  be
          present on all sessions of a multi session disk, except you want
          to create a session that will be the last session on the  media.
          The  fixation  will  be  done  in  a way that allows the CD/DVD-
          Recorder to append additional sessions later. This  is  done  by
          generation  a  TOC  with a link to the next program area. The so
          generated media is  not  100%  compatible  to  manufactured  CDs
          (except  for  CDplus).   Use only for recording of multi session
          CDs.  If this option is present, the default track type  is  CD-
          ROM  XA mode 2 form 1 and the sector size is 2048 bytes.  The XA
          sector subheaders will be created by the drive.  The Sony drives
          have  no hardware support for CD-ROM XA mode 2 form 1.  You have
          to specify the -data option in order  to  create  multi  session
          disks  on  these drives.  As long as wodim does not have a coder
          for converting data sectors to audio sectors, you need to  force
          CD-ROM  sectors  by  including  the  -data option if you like to
          record a multisession disk in SAO mode.  Not  all  drives  allow
          multisession CDs in SAO mode.
```

Comment: Thanks for you quick reply, I want to burn an video files and i want to burn multi session DVD, is it possible with wodim ?

Comment: Now that I don't know... I remember that not all standalone players can handle multisession dvd's, and I do know that k3b has some multisession support, it's my go-to for burning, despite it's larger size counting dependency on kde packages. Found some wodim multisession info, adding to answer. And feel free to upvote/up-arrow &/or select/check-mark an answer if it seems like a good one :)